# Hp Laserjet M1132 MFP recognized but no printing

Tags: drivers, printer, plugins

I've been facing troubles with my printer for 3 weeks, I cannot find a solution. These are the symptoms: When I run

hp-testpage error: Unable to communicate with printer HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP. Please check the printer and try again.

It is recognized:

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0cf3:e005 Atheros Communications, Inc. Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:28c1 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Bus 001 Device 013: ID 03f0:042a Hewlett-Packard LaserJet M1132 MFP Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

hp-check launch no errors. hplip-3.17.10 is currently running and its plugin but launch error saying something about "missing plugin required"

I can scan but no print. It didn't have any problems 3 weeks ago and I could print but now i can't after installing some pdf programs.

Comment: You might want to add that you are using Linux - and include your distro.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on Linux Mint 19.1.